# How does PnP manager determine the appropriate function driver?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, wdm

I am learing the loading  process of  Windows Driver.
But I cannot understand a part of the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/install/step-3--the-driver-for-the-device-is-installed

In this article, there is the following description.

**"4. The PnP manager loads the appropriate function driver and any optional filter drivers for the device."**

I have a question about above description.
How does the PnP manager determine the appropriate function driver?

For example, 
when a USB memory is plugged into a Windows PC then PnP manager will load disk.sys after loading a driver relating USB.
In this case, I want to know why PnP manager could judge that the device corresponds to disk.sys.
(seeing somewhere in registry? sending some requests to bus driver? and so on.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when bus driver detect and report *PDO* device PnP manager send several [`IRP_MJ_PNP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-pnp) to *PDO* device. including [`IRP_MN_QUERY_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/irp-mn-query-id) for get [*Device Identification Strings*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-identification-strings)

then formated registry key path in form

```
\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\<BusQueryDeviceID>\<BusQueryInstanceID>
```

in place `<BusQueryDeviceID>` string returned by device for `BusQueryDeviceID` and in place `<BusQueryInstanceID>` string returned by device for `BusQueryInstanceID` (`Parameters.QueryId.IdType`)

this key opened or created. then was query for `BusQueryHardwareIDs` and `BusQueryCompatibleIDs`. result of this query saved in `HardwareID` and `CompatibleIDs` `REG_MULTI_SZ` values.

and then PnP manager look for `Service` `REG_SZ` value under this key - if it already exist - the driver ( `\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<Service>`) loaded and it [`AddDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540521(v=vs.85).aspx) called with this *PDO*. if this value yet not set - was search via installed inf files in system - for best match `HardwareID` and `CompatibleIDs`. if found driver - result saved under `Service` `REG_SZ` value, for not search next time